# updating NVM Node Version Manager creationix version

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

Is deleting and then re-installing NVM the only way to update it? I have read many articles on how to install NVM (Node Version Manager - creationix flavor), I have not ready any other articles relating to updating Node Version Manager. I am being lazy and probably even more ignorant, but I haven't seen this question asked yet.

Comment: I'd recommend using `n`: https://www.npmjs.org/package/n. It's simpler than `nvm`, and upgrading can just be done through `npm`.

Comment: @TravisWebb does n have iojs?

Comment: Yes, the version in master supports iojs: https://github.com/tj/n. I'm just waiting for more thorough testing before I publish to npm

Answer (score 2):

Running the install script will attempt to update `nvm` if it's already installed ([link to source](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/b6f1c156da0a998442c1c0b638082390118085ce/install.sh#L31-L36)):

```
if [ -d "$NVM_DIR/.git" ]; then
  echo "=> nvm is already installed in $NVM_DIR, trying to update"
  printf "\r=> "
  cd "$NVM_DIR" && git pull 2> /dev/null || {
    echo >&2 "Failed to update nvm, run 'git pull' in $NVM_DIR yourself.."
  }
```

For example, for the `0.10.0` version:

> curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.10.0/install.sh | sh

For more information see the readme for nvm: https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Comment: Thanks, I tried the curl method after trying cloning the repo (miserable failure, didn't want to overwrite existing installation--could have forced the overwrite but that is work) and was successful. Even NVM is part of my work avoidance as some of the SSGs used outdated nodejs versions, NVM simplifies and avoids the installing, uninstalling and reinstalling cycle to use the older nodejs versions

Comment: Of course, yes, nvm is very useful for switching between node versions -- or for nothing else than just having the node install in your home directory (rather than in a possible root permissions only directory)